# How to find the ip-address of an RT-N66U accesspoint

Tags: wireless-access-point, ip-address

I just setup an Asus RT-N66U wireless router with an IP address of 192.168.1.3.  After I got it working, I connected it downstream from a TL-R600VPN router, disabled its DHCP and then changed it (Asus router) to function as an access point.  The (Asus) device works fine as an access point with all my Apple devices connected to it wirelessly.  But when I changed it from a router mode to access point mode, it changed its IP address from 192.168.1.3 to something else, and now I can't access it to make any changes.  Short of resetting the device, is there anyway to fid the new IP address?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Angry IP Scanner for these kinds of tasks for years (http://angryip.org/). You can just scan your entire subnet and see what it finds. You may or may not see its hostname, but you'll at least see which IP addresses are alive.